# Create an array of arrays from a list in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl, data-structures

I want to  create an array of arrays from a list of objects. but how to reset the array variable (@row and reuse it to hold items in the next sections)? I know the @row is declared once, when it is pushed into the array, emptying it will empty the @arrays too. How can I reset @row while not empty @arrays?

```
 use Data::Dumper;

    # sample data, could be a long list for complex data types
    my @list = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20);

    my @arrays;
    my @row;
    my $numSub = 10;

    foreach my $itm (@$list)  {
       if (scalar(@row) == $numSub) 
       {   
          push @arrays, \@row;
          @row = (); # clear array, cleared the array of arrays
          push @row, $itm;
        }
        else {
          push @row, $itm;
       }
   }
   # push the last reminder
    push @arrays, \@row;

   Dumper @arrays; # nothing
```

Comment: I expect @arrays has two arrays with (1, , 10) and (11,, 20).

Answer (score 1):

Create a new anonymous array instead of just taking a reference, or all your elements of @arrays will point to the same array ref.

```
push @arrays, [@row];
```

Also, if you're goal is just to build groups of 10 or less, then you can use the below method instead:

```
while (@list) {
    push @array, [splice @list, 0, 10];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Put `my @row` inside of your `foreach` loop instead of outside. Then it will be a distinct variable every time through the loop.

Incidentally, there are nicer ways to write this, for example:

```
my @copy = @list;
while (@copy) {
  push @arrays, [ splice @copy, 0, $numSub ];
}
```

or

```
use List::Util 'max';
for (my $i = 0 ; $i < @list ; $i += $numSub) {
  push @arrays, [ @list[ $i .. max($i + $numSub, $#list) ] ];
}
```

or

```
use List::MoreUtils 'natatime';
my $iter = natatime $numSub, @list;
while (my @vals = $iter->()) {
  push @arrays, \@vals;
}
```

Comment: If you put `my @row` inside the loop then it will only ever contain one element.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code as it stands that prevent it from working in the first place.

- You must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of every Perl program. This would have alerted you to the second problem
- You are looping over `@$list`, which would be fine if `$list` was an array reference, but the data you have defined is in `@list` and you need to use that
- The `Dumper` function just *returns* a formatted string. At present you are just discarding it. To see it you need to use `print Dumper \@arrays`
- As it stands, `@arrays` contains multiple references to the *same* array. You must *copy* `@row` to a new temporary array each time it is added to the list. The simplest way to do this is just `push @arrays, [ @row ]`

This program does what you require.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my @list = 1 .. 20;

my @arrays;
my @row;
my $numSub = 10;

for my $itm (@list) {
  if (@row == $numSub) {
    push @arrays, [@row];
    @row = ();
  }
  push @row, $itm;
}

push @arrays, [@row];

print Dumper \@arrays;
```

**output**

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            1,
            2,
            3,
            4,
            5,
            6,
            7,
            8,
            9,
            10
          ],
          [
            11,
            12,
            13,
            14,
            15,
            16,
            17,
            18,
            19
          ]
        ];
```